# Quite basic JQuery Animation-queuing, ain't working though

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, queueing

So, I got this great (?) idea to build my own tabsystem, as none of the scripts I've tried worked as I hoped.

I've got a list with links, and a couple of divs which are hidden to begin with. Click a LI and any visible div hides whereafter the selected link/div fades in.

HTML

```
<ul>
<li id="tab1">Link</li>
<li id="tab2">Link</li>
<li id="tab3">Link</li>
</ul>

<div id="tab1div">Content</div>
<div id="tab2div">Content</div>
<div id="tab3div">Content</div>
```

JS

```
$('li').click(function(){

    $('div:visible').fadeOut(1000)
    .queue(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('div#' + id + "div").fadeIn('slow');
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
});
```

Now, the problem is with the animations (apart from the script not working). I'm aiming for a fadeOut('fast') for any visible DIV, then a fadeIn('slow') for the selected li/div. Queued, that is.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery fadeOut can have two parameters, the second being function called after the animation completes, so this is probably what you want:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('div:visible').fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $('#' + id + "div").fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked fine if one of the divs was visible from the start. Possible to have them all hidden to start with?

Comment: You'd have to check if `$('div:visible')` is empty and ignore the `fadeOut` part if it is.